# How to capture emails only from an uploaded to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I can't seem to figure out how to remove all the unnecessary fields from an uploaded csv to mysql using php and placing my results in one column.

What I am currently doing is having someone upload their csv through my website and trying to collect only the email addresses from that csv.

Those emails could be in different rows or columns and there is no way for me to know ahead of time. I am trying to only capture the emails into mysql and store them in one column from that csv. (obviously I am weeding out anything that doesn't contain the @ symbol).

I hope this makes sense and I could really use the help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The usual process I go through when this needs to happen, is ask for consistent "headers" on the CSV.
I can then parse out the header to find which column the email is on.

```
<?php
$emailIndex = "none";
//CSV files saved on windows tend to behave weird on our linux server if we use fgetcsv
$file = file_get_contents("pathtofile/file.csv);
$file = str_replace("\r", "", $file);
$rows = explode("\n", $file);
$header = str_getcsv($rows[0], ",", '"', "\\");
unset($rows[0]);
foreach ($header as $index => $field) {
    if (trim($field) == "Email") {
        $emailIndex = $index;
        break;
    }
}
if (is_numeric($emailIndex)) {
    //Your execution code here.
}
```

The only other way would be to do precisely what you're already doing. Trying to find an index that contains an @ symbol, and hoping that symbol isn't used anywhere else. You could also check for com/net/org. But once you start doing that, you'll realize you can have basically any combination of .something for a website.

Unfortunately, consistency is key in business and programming. It's kind of unavoidable.

To attempt and check for an email though, you can try this (This is continuing from the explode in the above code).

```
foreach($rows as $rowIndex => $row) {
    $emails = array();
    foreach ($row as $fieldIndex => $field) {
        if (strpos($field, "@") !== false) {
            $email = strtolower($field);
            if (strpos($email, "com") !== false
                || strpos($email, "org") !== false
                || strpos($email, "net") !== false) {
                $emails[] = $email;
            }
        }
        if (count($emails) == 4) {
            //insert sql here using the array
            //Btw you should run mysql_real_escape_string() to sanitize data
            //Actually, you should probably use mysqli...


            //Break out of this loop at the end.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I edited the code a bit to reflect the idea that you wanted to enter 4 emails into your database from each row.
If you only want 1, then where I have $emails[] = $email, you can actually just put your sql code and call a break. As well as getting rid of the 2nd if statement.

If you don't know how many emails you might get per row, then you can remove the if (count(emails) == 4).
Instead of the if statement and your code going there, simply call your sql code at the end of the inner foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I would be looking for the index that contains the symbol @. I am having different companies upload their csv's through the website and they will have different columns. As such, I am just trying to weed out the emails. My understanding of your code above (and I appreciate the time), would look for a header in that csv and utilize that to recognize which column to grab. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct.
I'll modify my answer a bit to include code for detecting an "email" (quotes because it could also detect other things) on each individual row(Sometimes I get columns and rows mixed up).

Comment: Thanks for the modification. Where would I put this based on my code I listed above? Thanks again for the help, I really appreciate it. I've gotten to this final step in my process after weeks and I'm just stumped. Not enough experience :)

Comment: My code would pretty much replace all of your code, except for the query, which goes where I put //yourcode to insert it here.
However, looking at your code there is a modification that will have to be made again.
One moment.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and the explanation. I will try to piece it together and see what I get. What's throwing me off is I have a csv upload page using a <form> with the action taking the person to a new page that submits and utilizes the csv. I am confused about the pathtofile and how to figure out where that file is being stored to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot easier way

`$csv = file_get_contents("csv.csv);
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]+/",$csv, $matches);
var_dump($matches);`

Im sure You can find a lot better regexp for email

Comment: Where would I put that code? Sorry I don't know how to make it look like code on the forum :( Here is a little of what I have:if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$handle = fopen($file,"r");
while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false)
{
$email0 = $tablename;
$email1 = $fileop[0];
$email2 = $fileop[1];
$email3 = $fileop[2];
$email3 = $fileop[3]; 


mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$tablename." (email0,email1,email2,email3) VALUES ('$email0','$email1','$email2','$email3')");

}
}